# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.Stream' to 'Stream'

Tags: c#, asp.net, io, stream

I'm using the following code in order to stream a video on the aspx page and showing to the user.

But I get the following error in running the code:

> CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.Stream' to 'Stream'

May you please help me whats wrong with this code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

public partial class Stream : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream stream = null;
        int bytesToRead = 10000;
        byte[] buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest fileReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("the url");
            HttpWebResponse fileResp = (HttpWebResponse)fileReq.GetResponse();
            if (fileReq.ContentLength > 0)
                fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength;
            stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream();
            var resp = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            resp.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            resp.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "ali" + "\"");
            resp.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileResp.ContentLength.ToString());
            int length;
            do
            {
                if (resp.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
                    resp.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                    resp.Flush();
                    buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];
                }
                else
                {
                    length = -1;
                }
            } while (length > 0);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of code gives you the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream();
```

This line is throwing compilation error I believe. 
Your stream referance is of type Class **stream**. Please use

```
System.IO.Stream stream = null;
```

while initializing.. :)

Answer (score 0):

stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream(); is wrong

The declare of the function as follow
public override Stream GetResponseStream()

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream(v=vs.110).aspx

you can change the code to (NetworkStream)  fileResp.GetResponseStream();

To explain it in more detail, the Stream is an abstract class, it should initialize from its child class, in your case, you give an abstract object with abstract class type which violate this rule.

Answer (score 0):

Your class name is the same as the type returned by `.GetResponseStream()`. When you do `Stream stream` it defines `stream` as an object or your class not of `System.IO.Stream`. You have a couple of options. One is you can declare it as following:

```
System.IO.Stream stream = null;
```

Another is define your own for it as a using statement outside the namespace

```
using IOStream = System.IO.Stream;
```

Then you can use `IOStream` everywhere you need like this:

```
IOStream stream = null;
```

Comment: yes you have defined it wrong `Stream stream = null`. You will need to define it as `System.IO.Stream stream = null`